# What's the difference between astonishing and astounding?

Tags: differences

They both seem very similar to me, too similar to make a distinction.

### astonishing

> Something that is astonishing is very surprising

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/astonishing)

> very surprising

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/astonishing)

> ​very surprising; difficult to believe

[Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/astonishing)

### astounding

> If something is astounding, you are shocked or amazed that it could exist or happen.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/astounding)

> extremely surprising or shocking

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/astounding)

> ​so surprising that it is difficult to believe

[Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/astounding)

Comment: I think they're very similar; but astounding applies a bit more of a sense of wonder, while astonishing could just mean surprising in the moment, like someone jumping out at you naked. Just my intuition.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with an example where only one of them works.  They're very close.  "Astounding" is maybe slightly more appropriate when describing an incredible display of skill.  Like "an astounding feat of strength."  But "astonishing" also works there.  "Astonishing," on the other hand, might be more often used (particularly in recent years in internet headlines) to describe very bad misbehavior.  "Astounding," however, would also make sense in that context.

Comment: Note that Oxford _Learner's_ Dictionary gives 'astonishing' as a synonym for 'astounding'.